# Passing parameter between classes via delegates or...?

Tags: c#, class, delegates

I'd need to pass some variables between classes, I have a following code snippet to explain the situation. Note the following code are from app1, the SimpleScene() class is the entry point.

```
class SimpleScene {
    bool isReady;
    bool result;

    Protected override Run() {
        // instance of class StateMonitor
        StateMonitor sm = new StateMonitor;
        Listener(sm);
        sm.proc();

        while(!isReady) {}

        result = func();
        if (result) {
            // need to inform StateMonitor to do a certain action, e.g. set bool flag = true, and StateMonitor does something iff flag == true;
        }
    }

    void OnReady(bool isOnReady) {
        if(isOnReady)
             isReady = true;
    }

    Private void Listener(StateMonitor sm) {
        sm.OnReady += new StateMonitor.ready(OnReady);
    }

    bool func() {
        //do something...
    }

}

class StateMonitor {
    public delegates void ready(bool isReady);
    public event ready OnReady;

    // start app2 as a new process
    public void proc() {
        Process p_app2 = new Process();
        // omit other startinfo for app2.
        p_app2.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(outputHandler);
        p_app2.Start();
        p_app2.BeginOutputReadLine();
    }        

    public void outputHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs line) {
        // omit output data line match
        if (OnReady != null)
            OnReady(true);
    }
}
```

class StateMonitor starts another application - let's say app2 - and read the stdout from app2. Depending on the output string format, it will do different things.

My problem lies in the code comments, where I want to inform StateMonitor to do certain thing once flag == true; How could I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to use threads. You'll fire off a thread in StateMonitor that loops based on a boolean. Then set that boolean from SimpleScene when you want to do something when that flag is true. There are tons of examples out there. Check here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4(v=vs.90).aspx

Worker = StateMonitor

WorkerThreadExample = SimpleScene

Comment: Thank you! yet I have one more question: would the Thread and the Listener conflict each other? In the above code, I have line "sm.proc();" in the link you gave me, it starts the function within the thread as "Thread workerThread = new Thread(workerObject.DoWork);". Should I remove my line or keep both?

Comment: It's up to you. You can keep `sm.proc()` and then have that proc() function start the thread that loops and waits for a flag to be set.